# Android studio giving get MotionRecognitionManager error while loading ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am getting "Get MotionrecognitionManager" error when loading a listView inside a fragment. Basically I am displaying a json data in listview and the page just loads with blank data(also tried with constant data) list is not loading successfully. i am unable to solve the issue so wants to know the reason behind this. thanks

Comment: Please post a code snippet in question, along with the logcat output

Comment: It is just showing 1 line: D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager

Comment: Though it is working in simple activity but when I am using listView in fragment it is showing me the above error. App is not crashing but just showing blank